# Unable to use created neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, cql, cypher-shell

I had created a **neo4j** database, which was working perfectly.

But now, when i try to use the database created by me, using following command:

```
:USE foo;
```

it gives error:

```
Unable to get a routing table for database 'foo' because this database is unavailable
```

I tried checking the status of database using command :

```
SHOW DATABASE foo;
```

It shows the currentStatus of foo as "offline". I have tried starting the database using

```
START DATABASE foo;
```

but no luck!

Although, I can use default "neo4j" and "system" databases. Only the new database which I have created, dose not work now.

If someone knows the solution, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally managed to solve the issue. It was because of file permission of a file  `/var/lib/neo4j/data/transactions/foo/neostore.transaction.db.26`.

May be somehow the user neo4j lost access to this file. I looked into the debug log file, `/var/log/neo4j/debug.log` and found exception message `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/neo4j/data/transactions/foo/neostore.transaction.db.26` then I changed the file permission for neo4j user using command:

```
chown neo4j /var/lib/neo4j/data/transactions/foo//neostore.transaction.db.26
```

After this, i started the database and it worked

Comment: if this answer is the correct one, please mark it as `Accepted Answer`

Comment: Correct in my case also. Additionally, the `/var/lib/neo4j/databases/foo` directory had become owned by root, and I had to `chown -R neo4j:neo4j` that as well. The cause of my situation was almost certainly that I ran `neo4j-admin database import full  ...` as root. I thought that was how you were supposed to run it but maybe not? That's certainly what did it though, I had a stuck transaction and DB owned by root after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CREATE DATABASE foo
```

And then start it

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't work. It gives error: Failed to create the specified database 'foo': Database already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `neostore.transaction.db.0` file from the existing `data/transactions/neo4j` folder to your own db `data/transactions/<your_db>` folder.